# How to Change font of Text in MaterialTabHost in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I am using MaterialTabHost for displaying tabs. I wanted to change the font of the MaterialTabHost when onTabSelected.  I tried to get the textview of the same. but cant figured it out.  I referred https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs. 
any help would be appriciated.

Here is my XML .

```
                    <!-- for Text Tabs -->
                    <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
                        android:id="@+id/materialTabHost_MainActivity"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
                        app:accentColor="@color/white"
                        app:primaryColor="@color/main_blue_light"
                        app:textColor="@color/white"

                        />
```

so how do we change the font ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I change font of text into tab when it is create:

```
Typeface fontRobotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf");
MaterialTab tab = new MaterialTab(getApplicationContext(), false);
View tabView = tab.getView();
TextView text = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.text);
tab.setText(pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
text.setTypeface(fontRobotoRegular);
tab.setTabListener(this);
tabHost.addTab(tab);
```

So if you want to change font when the tab is selected you can do something like this on onPageSelected of your ViewPager:

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    ...
    Typeface fontBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf");
    TextView text = (TextView) tabs.getCurrentTab().getView().findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setTypeface(fontBold);
    ...
}
```